# SSRS - How to repeat entire first column on each new page for Matrix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

How can I get the entire first row of a matrix column(aka Row Headers) to repeat when the columns of the matrix expand to new pages?

I've tried many solutions I've found online, but none of them have helped. I checked repeat row headers/column headers under Tablix Properties, under advanced > Row groups I set all static elements to Fixed Data/RepeatOnNewPage = True/KeepWithGroup = AFter. None of these have worked.

An example of the report setup/First column. https://i.stack.imgur.com/bODJO.jpg

I would expect the entire first column to repeat on additional pages when the number of columns spans more than 1 page.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes to get around the wonky-ness of SSRS, sometimes the best solution is an alternate solution.

If everything you are trying isn't working, you could always put labels in the page header that way it guaranteed repeats. However this solution isn't ideal because of the extra whitespace it creates in the header even if you hide the textboxes.